# Get custom properties like `Created` and `Description` in Display Templates of ContentBySearchWebPart

Tags: 2013, search, search-results, display-template

I use Display Templates for rendering ContentBySearchWebPart. Nice feature, but how I can add custom properties from search results list item into Display Template?

For example, I have a template, `some_listitem_template.html`:

```
<!--#_
var line1 = $getItemValue(ctx, "Line 1");
var line2 = $getItemValue(ctx, "Line 2");
var line3 = $getItemValue(ctx, "Line 3");

for (var p in ctx.CurrentItem)
{
    console.log(p + ":" + $getItemValue(ctx, p));
}

line1.overrideValueRenderer($contentLineText);
line2.overrideValueRenderer($contentLineText);
_#-->
<div class="news-date">_#= line3 =#_</div>
<div class="news-title">
   <a href="_#= linkURL =#_" title="_#= $htmlEncode(line1.defaultValueRenderer(line1)) =#_">_#= line2 =#_</a>
</div>
```

And I have Property Mapping declaration string
`<mso:ManagedPropertyMapping msdt:dt="string">'Link URL':'Path','Line 1':'Title','Line 2':'Description', 'Line 3':'Created'</mso:ManagedPropertyMapping>`

But these properties (Description and Created) is always empty. Debug information from `console.log` show me that `ContextItem` has a pretty small collection of properties:

```
Rank:0 
DocId:46734
Path:http://someurl/news/Page-1.aspx
Title:Some title
FileExtension:aspx
SecondaryFileExtension:aspx
OriginalPath:somepath
PartitionId:0c37852b-34d0-418e-91c6-2ac25af4be5b5
UrlZone:1
AAMEnabledManagedProperties:AttachmentURI;deeplinks;DefaultEncodingURL;ExternalMediaURL;HierarchyUrl;OrgParentUrls;OrgUrls;OriginalPath;ParentLink;Path;PictureThumbnailURL;PictureURL;PublishingImage;recommendedfor;ServerRedirectedEmbedURL;ServerRedirectedPreviewURL;ServerRedirectedURL;SiteLogo;SitePath;SPSiteURL;UserEncodingURL
RenderTemplateId:~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Search/Item_Default.js
QueryRuleId:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
```

Suppose its because Search Configuration, but where is this place exactly?

Comment: Great question, i would love to know the answer as well - fighting with it at the moment

Comment: I don't fully undestand how is this mechanism works eventually, but right now I'm using fields with names `CommentsOWSMTXT` and `ArticleStartDateOWSDATE` for my purposes. These fields is indexed and mapping to ordinary Article Content Type columns and Display Tempalte works just fine.

Comment: how are you deploying that display template? I had the same issue as you do, and turns out I had to specify some extra stuff in element.xml. Let me know if that's the case

Comment: What extra stuff are you talking about? Any examples? At the moment we are not using any *.wsp packages at all. In my case it's only a client-side SharePoint development (like masterpages, styles, layouts, displaytemplates, javascript libs) using Node.js and deploy process is as simple as copying *.html files via `grunt deploy`. Take a look, for example [generator-sp2013](https://github.com/kmees/generator-sp2013/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Things to check:

1. Go to /_catalogs/masterpage and find your displaytemplate's js file. View its properties and make sure you see the mappings in question in Managed Property Mappings property.
2. Go to Centra Admin -> Manage Service Applications -> Search Application and look at your schema - make sure that Description and Created are existing managed properties and tehy have corresponding crawled properties.

Comment: I would add a 3rd step, which would be check in the .html file. after numerous failed attempts, it just so happen to work immediately after I checked in the file. I was seeing the updated changes (saving .html saves .js automatically) but the fields were empty

Answer (score 2):

One other thing to check, if you are using result types to display items:

Go to /_layouts/15/manageresulttypes.aspx?level=sitecol at the site collection level, and /_layouts/15/manageresulttypes.aspx?level=site at the site level, and click update if there is a property sync warning.

[image]
This needs to be done every time the mappings are changed in the template